# Optional query parameters with InsertPermission() in PyDrive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, pydrive

Is it possible to send a value for optional query parameters using `InsertPermission()` in PyDrive? The PyDrive documentation seems to ignore how to handle toggling optional parameters like `sendNotificationEmails`.

I need to add permissions to files for specific users, not anyone, without sending a notification email, and `sendNotificationEmails` is set to `True` by default.

I've considered modifying files.py's definition for the function to the following, but I'm not sure if this will work and haven't edited a library before:

```
def InsertPermission(self, new_permission):
  """Insert a new permission. Re-fetches all permissions after call.

  :param new_permission: The new permission to insert, please see the official Google Drive API guide on permissions.insert for details.

  :type new_permission: object

  :return: The permission object.
  :rtype: object
  """
  file_id = self.metadata.get('id') or self['id']
  try:
    permission = self.auth.service.permissions().insert( fileId=file_id, body=new_permission, sendNotificationEmails=False).execute(http=self.http)
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    raise ApiRequestError(error)
  else:
    self.GetPermissions()  # Update permissions field.

  return permission
```

Comment: Don't modify the library's code. Send a feature request to the PyDrive maintainer, and until it's implemented have a copy of the modified code in your own project.

Comment: PyDrive maintainer here, open a bug here: https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive/issues. You can fork the library and make your changes. If they work, I'm more than happy to merge them into the main library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying optional parameters is now possible as additional parameters to the `InsertPermission()` function like so:

```
file1.InsertPermission({'type': 'user',
                        'value': 'insert@email.here',
                        'role': 'reader'}, sendNotificationEmails=False)
```

Please see the official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) for all parameters available.

**Note**: You will currently (Apr 2017) need to install the development version of the library for this feature. This version of PyDrive can be installed like so:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive.git@development#egg=PyDrive
```

Comment: for google api directly (V3), it is `sendNotificationEmail`, singular